# How do I get the percentage of dates that exceed the due date?

Tags: excel

I have a excel spreadsheet where I am trying to get the percentage of the dates that are on time and the ones that are not on time are has red filling, **The 'Completed Date'** field  is the field I am working in, and the **'Estimated date complete'** is the dates that if the **'completed date'** surpass the **'estimated date complete'** it is highlighted red.

I have tried a Count IF function but it does not work

I'm trying to get the percentage of ON time dates

[image: Excel worksheet]

[image: Excel]

[image: excel]

Answer (score 0):

If *Date Completed* is in column H, this should calculate the percentage of completed dates that are earlier than or equal to the estimated completed dates.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(H2:INDEX(H:H, MATCH(1E+99, H:H))<=G2:INDEX(G:G, MATCH(1E+99, H:H))))/COUNT(H2:INDEX(H:H, MATCH(1E+99, H:H)))
```

Format the cell as a percentage.